# cloudsim doesn't accept .pem file arguments

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Either there is a cloudsim-1.0.0 bug, or a problem with .pem files

```
./create_cloudsim.py my.name@gmail.com pk-XYZ.pem sa-XYZ.pem
results in the error message:
inside/cgi-bin
cloudsimd/launchers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_cloudsim.py", line 40, in 
    import common
ImportError: No module named commoncode
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/475/cloudsim-doesn%27t-accept-.pem-file-arguments/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When you make an AWS key pair and save it on your machine, it is saved as a .pem file pair. It would be convenient to be able to just use these files.

---

Originally posted by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) with karma: 223 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hugomatic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/59/hugomatic/) on 2012-12-11**:
CloudSim uses Access Keys (not key pairs, sorry) to connect to AWS. AWS provides them on the Access Keys tab on the AWS Security Credentials page.